# C# Textbox.Text into SQL SmallMoney

Tags: c#, sql, sqldatatypes, formatexception

I have the following code

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductCode, Range, Type, Size, Description, Cost, Barcode) VALUE ('" + txbx_ProductCode.Text + "', '" + txbx_Range.Text + "','" +
                    txbx_Type.Text + "' , '" + txbx_Size.Text + "', '" + txbx_Description.Text + "' , '" + decimal.Parse(txbx_Cost.Text) + "' , '" + txbx_Barcode.Text + "')";
```

I get the following FormatException on this line:
[FormatException Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yUx9.png)

I suspect there is an issue with me parsing the .text. I've tried parsing to float, double, Decimal and decimal. It's the same on all cases.

The values entered are between 20000.00 and 100.00 always having 2 decimals so they never exceed the smallmoney value.

Comment: Please, please, **please** for the love of all that's holy, use prepared statements.

Comment: @IanKemp thank you for bringing this up. No one ever told me about it, but I'll start having it as a standard.

Comment: Be careful with SQL injections.. Use prepared statements.

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCode", txbx_ProductCode.Text);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly thank you to E.J. Brennan and Ian Kemp for putting me on the right path. I don't know how to add a commendation or whatever it is called on StackOverflow but thank you.

I ended up adding everything into prepared statements and got a few errors but they were different to the one I got earlier and easier to squash.

The new method looks like this:

```
using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            //open database (closed below)
            sqlCon.Open();

            //sql query that inserts data into table using user inputs
            String query = "INSERT INTO Product(ProductCode, Range, Type, Size, Description, Cost, Barcode) VALUES(@ProductCode, @Range, @Type, @Size, " +
                "@Description, @Cost, @Barcode) ";

            //initialise sqlcommand using the query and connection
            using var command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);

            //assign values and prepare them
            command.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25).Value = txbx_ProductCode.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Range", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txbx_Range.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txbx_Type.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Size", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = txbx_Size.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txbx_Description.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Cost", SqlDbType.SmallMoney).Value = Decimal.Parse(txbx_Cost.Text);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Barcode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 13).Value = txbx_Barcode.Text;

            //prepare the added statements
            command.Prepare();
            //execute using nonquery (cause of no expected return data)
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close database connection (opened above)
            sqlCon.Close();
           
            //display succesfull insertion
            MessageBox.Show("Product succesfully added.");
        }
```

PS. Sorry for all the commenting, I just like knowing at a glance whats what.

And yes, "for the love of all that's holy, use prepared statements".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Product (ProductCode, Range, Type, Size, Description, Cost, Barcode) VALUE ('" + txbx_ProductCode.Text + "', '" + txbx_Range.Text + "','" +
                    txbx_Type.Text + "' , '" + txbx_Size.Text + "', '" + txbx_Description.Text + "' , " + decimal.Parse(txbx_Cost.Text) + " , '" + txbx_Barcode.Text + "')";
```

you don't need to add single quotes around the cost, after converting to decimal.

In fact, you probably don't even need to Decimal.Parse. That said, will the above code should work, it is really not robust, so you probably want to consider validating all of your input before you build an sql string and should spend a bit of time about learning about how to prevent sql injection; your code is susceptible, and it would be pretty easy for someone to enter values into the input fields that would execute arbitrary sql queries, even deleting rows and tables.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: I know directly using the user input like this is not good practice, this is just a technical demo. After adding all the sql functionality I was planning on breaking them all up into their own methods using a validate method or something similar.

Comment: I tried removing the single quotes and removing the Decimal.Parse. Same error. I'll try putting everything in a validate method before it gets sent to the query tonight and give an update.

Comment: you should print out the generated sql statement with consol.writeline(query), and then copy/paste it into something like SSMS and try to execute it - that is how I would go about debugging it.

Comment: It would also help to show us your table definition - I was assuming the only numeric field is 'cost', but if there are others, you will have the same problem.

Comment: cost is the only numeric field yes. I'll try the SSMS debug and post an update here. If it wasn't painfully obvious I am new to C# coding so I just wanted to say thank you for helping.

Comment: another tip, if you are using sql server it should VALUES, not VALUE